# Css linked but doesn't work in my django website

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Everything goes normal , I didn't find any kind of error message . But my website can't load css file .
In the settings , debug is True . But I didn't find any error . Please help me to find out the error.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/fontawesome.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/tooplate-main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/owl.css' %}">

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{% static 'assets/images/header-logo.png' %}" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/custom.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/owl.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure that the static files exist at the specified path?, you can confirm this by inspecting the generated html page and opening the css url from there.

Comment: Which of these it can't load? Try to grab any of broken urls, open it manually in a separate tab, what's the http response status? And show your static folder structure.

Comment: do you have this STATIC_URL = '/static/' in your settings? also, are your static files in a folder named static at the root of your app?

Comment: @PeterNdungu , Yes , in the settings there is STATIC_URL = '/static/'. And all the static files is in a folder which name is static.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using development settings, `DEBUG = True`, if this `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in your installed apps, the static_url is set, the static files are at a folder called static at the root of your app and in the templates you `{% load static %}` the staticfiles should be served. If you have multiple locations for staticfiles explore [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Comment: also, i'd suggest using a cdn for thirdparty css such as bootstrap and fontawesome, saves you some time

Comment: be mindful of the folder structure, key folders in an app are templates and static, django needs these to be here when using the discussed settings

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` file add `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`.
It should look kinda like this:

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```